# Cybersource Payment Integration in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, payment, cybersource

I am trying to integrate Cybersource Payment for Hosted Checkout in our Expo React Native app.
Our e-commerce web application is build on Wordpress and it uses it's custom plugin provided by Cybersource.
So, a little help and guide would be appreciated, I just need to know how it's gonna be implemented.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it ?

Comment: Nope. I have contacted their support team but got no response.

Comment: Is there any hope? @INSARAMALAMSIDDIQUE